# ios-Restkit Tutorial for core data

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit

I am trying to use core data database for my IOS application.But i am not getting any tutorial to get any information about it.I want to now if there is any free tutorial for Restkit for IOS programming.i want to know how to use Restkit in my application.

Comment: You could have posted this question on google

Comment: i have not get any solution from there.I am only getting paid tutorial.I am not able to afford paid tutorial at this moment

Comment: 1. http://www.raywenderlich.com/13097/intro-to-restkit-tutorial  2. http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started        Since now you are involved in development please dont look for walk through tutorials instead rely on documentations.

Comment: the documentation is for older version of restkit.

Comment: Look at the RestKit github page for documentation on the latest version.

Comment: okay...i will check there..@wain...thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You can find RestKit core-data tutorial and Sample code from here

:https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit

First you have to download RestKit via terminal by GitHub.

In the main folder you find Examples folder which contain folder namely RKTwitterCoreData.

May this will help you out.

Comment: You can also consult this tutorial too http://madeveloper.blogspot.com/2013/01/ios-restkit-tutorial-code-for-version.html

Comment: Please let me know is this info is helpful to you, then kindly accept my answer so it will may help others. Thanks.

Comment: -1. you crave to get a bonus, but not attached to it, your response does not bear aid (((

Comment: Using cocoapods is easier.

Answer (score 0):

There is a step by step up-to-date (as of February 2015) tutorial on using RestKit with Core Data. You can find it here https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/restkit-tutorial-how-to-fetch-data-from-an-api-into-core-data-9326af750e10.